# Google Maps Sample project builds but stops on Android 4.4.2 w Google API's

Tags: android, google-maps, fatal-error

The actual sample Google Android Studio Project [CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/tree/master/tutorials/CurrentPlaceDetailsOnMap) which google provides as a tutorial seems to crash in an android 4.4.2 AVD with API 19 and also Google APIs.

Anyone can test it directly themselves. After you first open up the project in the current Android Studio 3.1 it gives you an Android Gradle Plugin Update Recommended dialog which I then run that update. Next it gives me a bunch of Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with implementation errors which I fix by replacing the references. I then replaced the GOOGLE_MAPS_API_KEY in the gradle.properties file with a key I received after signing up with google.  Then I build and run the app which then crashes with "**Unfortunately, Current Place Details has stopped.**" error. Note: The application runs on my 4.4 device but doesn't work in the AVD.

I have made *no modification to the original tutorial code* except changing compile to implementation and adding my google api key.  I notice that *if I have it skip* the line:

```
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

*Then it runs* but doesn't zoom into the correct location. I don't understand the output of the logcat trace but maybe it will help debug the issue.
Any recommendations how to keep testing it in the AVD without it crashing? Thanks.

Update: I am roughly trying to follow the stacktrace and it looks like the AVD is crashing on line 212:

```
new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
```

Here is the lower 1/2 of the logcat console:

```
04-08 22:50:57.911 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x005d
04-08 22:50:57.911 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.Context.isDeviceProtectedStorage, referenced from method tm.a
04-08 22:50:57.911 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 683: Landroid/content/Context;.isDeviceProtectedStorage ()Z
04-08 22:50:57.911 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0009
04-08 22:50:57.921 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 373K, 13% free 3258K/3740K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
04-08 22:50:57.921 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9K, 13% free 3316K/3796K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
    GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 13% free 3413K/3896K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
04-08 22:50:57.921 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 4.512MB for 1127532-byte allocation
04-08 22:50:57.931 4820-4829/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 10% free 4514K/5000K, paused 3ms, total 3ms
04-08 22:50:57.941 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 43K, 9% free 4711K/5168K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
04-08 22:50:57.941 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/ContextImpl: Failed to ensure directory: /storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap/cache
04-08 22:50:57.951 4820-4840/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.os.PowerManager.isInteractive, referenced from method om.a
04-08 22:50:57.951 4820-4840/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 1094: Landroid/os/PowerManager;.isInteractive ()Z
04-08 22:50:57.951 4820-4840/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003b
04-08 22:50:57.951 4820-4840/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/ActivityThread: ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
04-08 22:50:57.961 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 352K, 9% free 4992K/5452K, paused 1ms, total 2ms
04-08 22:50:58.001 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xb7978e70: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
04-08 22:50:58.021 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb7978e70: ver 2 0
04-08 22:50:58.021 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap E/EGL_emulation: tid 4820: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
04-08 22:50:58.021 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/HardwareRenderer: Backbuffer cannot be preserved
04-08 22:50:58.021 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
04-08 22:50:58.031 4820-4840/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 486K, 11% free 5225K/5820K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
04-08 22:50:58.041 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
04-08 22:50:58.041 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4d25b20)
04-08 22:50:58.041 4820-4820/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap, PID: 4820
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap.MapsActivityCurrentPlace$2.onComplete(MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java:212)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzf.run(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates not found.
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:0 and remote module com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates:4
    Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.googlecertificates, version >= 4
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method ar.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 102: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.ContextWrapper.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method ar.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 103: Landroid/content/ContextWrapper;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method o.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method p.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 725: Lo;.createCredentialProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap I/dalvikvm: Could not find method o.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext, referenced from method p.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 726: Lo;.createDeviceProtectedStorageContext ()Landroid/content/Context;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0002
    DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 58 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0012
    DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 57 (SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0021
    DexOpt: couldn't find static field Landroid/os/Build;.SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve static field 58 (SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS) in Landroid/os/Build;
04-08 22:50:59.971 4820-4866/com.example.currentplacedetailsonmap D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x0008
```

Comment: To resolve the "Authorization failure" see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup

Comment: Got a key as noted in the introduction paragraph above. It runs on my 4.4 android device but doesn't work in the AVD. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: @Andy sorry about that. I actually pasted my first logcat before I replaced the key. I was wondering how you knew I didn't originally replace the key until I saw it in my original posted logcat. I fixed my logcat as it is displayed now. It still doesn't run on the 4.4.2 AVD though but just runs on my device. Which isn't always available for me so I need it working on the AVD.

Answer (score 0):

So far from the stacktrace it looks like it crashes due to a null value in mLastKnownLocation.

I added a line to the original Google Maps tutorial MapsActivityCurrentPlace.java file:

```
if(mLastKnownLocation == null) { return; }
```

above

```
  mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
  new LatLng(mLastKnownLocation.getLatitude(),
  mLastKnownLocation.getLongitude()), DEFAULT_ZOOM));
```

to return to the map without zooming in if there was no mLastKnownLocation.

When you click on the map cross hair, you will then get an updated location.

Interesting though that the 4.4.2 AVD never had a previous location stored (probably in cache) which caused it to crash. I haven't tried a different version of an API on the AVD and guessing it might crash on other versions.